# Locating the directory for systemd scripts

Tags: centos, systemd

Tried to add a startup script for CentOS, but can't find upstart script directory (which typically is in `/etc/init` on my ubuntu system). I heard it's in `/usr/lib/systemd` but it's not on my system:

```
[root@ lib]# more /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

[root@ lib]# ls /usr/lib/systemd
ls: /usr/lib/systemd: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You confuse upstart and systemd. These are two distinct and unrelated (and competing, FWIW) init systems.

Answer (score 1):

`RHEL` 5 does not have `systemd`. Redhat Enterprise 5 and CentOS 5 use `sysvinit`, version 6 uses `upstart`, and version 7 uses `systemd`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @uwe-burger. Wonder where is the directory for start up script.  On my ubuntu system, it was in /etc/init.

Comment: Sorry, i have not used redhat 5 system, i thought it would be etc/init, i only know about redhat enterprise switching from upstart to systemd because of the systemd debate. Google redhat enterprise 5 and upstart you should find documentation.

Comment: Thanks @uwe-burger for the info about difference between ver 5 and 6!

Comment: From my understanding RHEL/CentOS 5 uses sysvinit, 6 uses upstart, 7 uses systemd.

Comment: Yes sorry i confused it. 5 sysvinit, 6 upstart and 7 is systemd.